# Can't upgrade pip for python3

Tags: upgrade, updates, python3, pip

I have pip installed for python3:

```
$ pip3 -V
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.4)
```

If I try to upgrade to Version 8, this is what I get:

```
$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
Downloading/unpacking pip from https://pypi.python.org/packages/9c/32/004ce0852e0a127f07f358b715015763273799bd798956fa930814b60f39/pip-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=0570520434c5b600d89ec95393b2650b
Downloading pip-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2MB): 1.2MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: pip
Found existing installation: pip 1.5.4
Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, owned by OS
Successfully installed pip
Cleaning up...
```

Can anyone tell me why it won't upgrade to a newer version?

Answer (score 2):

actually it was successful installation you can check it by typing

```
sudo pip3 -V
```

Comment: I get the same result if I add sudo: `$ sudo pip3 -V:
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.4)`

Comment: i try it on my laptop and got the same error as yours but when i check pip3 version with root permission i can see the new updated version please try to close your current terminal and open  a new one and try it with su

Comment: I just restarted my machine and it is still the same.

Comment: please post the output of    python3 --version

Comment: $ python3 --version:
Python 3.4.3

Comment: i don't know why its not working in your device.

Comment: Other people have recommended `sudo -H` from your home directory, which I believe is necessary because the system candidates have lower priority than the user ones. Using `sudo -H` there *should* be no ambiguity with another location/version, but it also sounds like the packaged version is not synchronized with Python's version. They'll contradict and subtly override one another based on who/where you are at the moment, but at the maintenance level there's no conflict, so the user must know best. A warning might be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Install anaconda and install everything at once.
[Click here for Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

Comment: Anaconda looks interesting! But for now I'd like to stick to virtualenv and pip. Maybe I'll give it a shot on my next project.

Comment: Anaconda install a lot of packages and some features as Jupyter Notebook. It's very easy to install and you save a lot of time. In other words, it prepares a nice pyhton environment. Take it a try.